# Multiply inherited method with same signature and exception in signature causing runtime error

Tags: java, inheritance, location, polymorphism

Can someone explain to me why I get a run time NoSuchMethodError error with the code Scratch.java below? I don't get an error if the method m1 does not throw any exception. I also don't get any error if the interfaces A, B, and X had no generic type M. I also don't get any error if Y directly implemented A and B instead of doing so via an intermediate interface X. But if I have all three -- the exception in the method signature, a generic type, and the intermediate interface -- I get a run time error as shown below. FYI, I checked that the types String and Long don't matter and could be anything, primitive or non-primitive.

I would appreciate any pointers to Java documentation, for example, 
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.4
or others for the method location rule that explains this observation.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {

interface A<M> {
    public int m1(String arg1, M arg2) throws IOException;
}

interface B<M> {
    public int m1(String arg1, M arg2) throws IOException;
}

interface X<M> extends A<M>, B<M> {
}

class Y<M> implements X<M> {
    @Override
    public int m1(String arg1, M arg2) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Invoked m1(String, M) from "
                + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return 1;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Y<Long> y = new Scratch().new Y<Long>();
    X<Long> x = y;
    String arg1 = "something";
    Long arg2 = 23L;// new String("fddsfs");
    try {
        y.m1(arg1, arg2); // gives no error
        x.m1(arg1, arg2);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        System.err.println("Method m1 not found in "
                + x.getClass().getSimpleName() + "; methods = "
                + Arrays.asList(x.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Invoked m1(String, M) from Y
Method m1 not found in Y; methods = [public int edu.umass.cs.scratch.Scratch$Y.m1(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object) throws java.io.IOException]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.umass.cs.scratch.Scratch$X.m1(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Long;)I
    at edu.umass.cs.scratch.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:417)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with JDK 1.8.0_61.

Comment: Tunaki, thanks for the quick response. I checked that I get the error with JDK 1.8.0_20 on Mac OS 10.9.5. I do not get the error with JDK 1.8.0_66 on Ubuntu 12.04.5.

Comment: I also get the error on Mac OS 10.10.5 with JDK 1.8.0_45.

Comment: More info: when I compile using JDK 1.8.0.20 as before on my Mac OS 10.9.5 and use JRE 1.8.0.73 to run it, I don't get any error.

Comment: And of course, using 1.8.0.74 to both compile and run causes no problems. So this seems to be a problem with JRE 1.8.0_45 or below on Mac OS 10.

Comment: Well, that's some nice narrowing :D. I didn't search a bug in the OpenJDK Jira but it sure looks like it.

Comment: I looked at this OpenJDK JIRA but didn't but didn't find any recent bugs that seem related. I can't find a way to post there or draw there attention to it. Is there a way?

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068692?jql=text%20~%20%22multiple%20inheritance%20interfaces%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC